# Detect that given element has been removed from the DOM without sacrificing performance

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I've got these:

```
const element = this.getElementById("victim")

function releaseKraken(targetElement) {}
```

I want the function to be called when `element` is removed from DOM.

I can imagine something like this:

```
element.onRemove(() => releaseKraken(element))
```

I understand that I need `MutationObserver`, but all the documentation I found focuses on watching given element's children, whereas I need to watch the element itself.

UPD: the question [How to detect element being added/removed from dom element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156453/how-to-detect-element-being-added-removed-from-dom-element)
 focuses on watching children of a given parent. I don't want to watch children or parent. I want to be notified when given element is removed from the DOM. Not it's children. And I don't want to set up a watcher on given element's parent (unless that's the only option) because it'll be a performance impact.

UPD2: if I set up a `MutationObserver` on `document`, this will result in the callback being triggered thousands or even millions of times per session, and each time the callback will have to filter a huge list of removed elements to see if it contains the one in question. That's just crazy.

I need something simple like I showed above. I want the callback to be triggered exactly once: when the given element is removed.

Comment: The only other method is the deprecated DOMNodeRemoved event. It probably won't hurt the performance since you'll observe just the node itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect element being added/removed from dom element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156453/how-to-detect-element-being-added-removed-from-dom-element)

Comment: Please frist do some research and then ask the question.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski I've seen that question. It focuses on watching children of a parent. I want to watch given element's removal, not its children and not its parent.

Comment: What is the problem of watching on the parent for its removal?

Comment: So bind it to `document` and then evry element is its children.

Comment: The problem is performance. Binding on a parent (not to mention `document`) will trigger the callback for unrelated elements. I'll have to fitler them out in order to decide whether the given element was removed or some other. Depending on the number of siblings, this may be a huge performance implication.

Comment: Even worse, the callback will keep firing after the element was removed. And `MutationObserver` API does not allow unobserving individual elements. >_<

Comment: [This](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/how-to-detect-if-element-is-added-or-removed-from-dom/) approach should help.

Comment: @RobC, you suggest watching `body`. The callback will be triggered thousands, maybe millons times per session, and on each trigger you have to iterate through a list of removed nodes in order to detect the one in question. That's crazy. I need something simple like `$(element).on('remove', e => releaseKraken(e))` that would fire exactly once.

Comment: `element.parentElement` instead of `document.body` will result in  fewer iterations (if tree structure is nested).

Comment: Depending on how fast you need to react, polling the state in setInterval callback like every 1 second may be the most performant solution e.g. document.contains(element) or element.parentNode.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov You want a watcher, but you don't want it to watch whole body, but it also can't watch any parent. What gives??

Comment: @RobC Your proposal will reduce the amount of unrelated triggers from millions to hundreds -- better, but still ugly. Also, you can't tell MutationObserver to unobserve individual elements (only purge all at once). This means that I'll have to use multiple MutationObservers -- one per every element I want to see removed.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski I don't want a watcher specifically. I want a simple solution for a simple, narrow task. The solution you suggest has unreasonable overhead. The fact that you can't think of a better solution does not make my question invalid.

Comment: Agreed - it's still ugly! and yes good point about MutationObserver purging all at once to unobserve - again ugly too.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add an event when something removes it? Or just poll it and see if it is there.

Comment: @epascarello 1. No, my use case involves watching arbitrary elements in a huge SPA. 2. Polling is a valid workaround, but also quite ugly.

Comment: are you in a position to touch the code that's actually removing the element?

Comment: Sounds like you really want something like the Custom Elements v1 `disconnectedCallback` (without actual Custom Elements of course!).

Comment: @JanWendland Yes, but the goal is to observe arbitrary elements. There are many thousands of DOM-mutating events, many of them template-driven, I can't hack into them all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you said, `MutationObserver` only allows you to detect when the children of an element are manipulated. That means you'll need to listen to the parent and check what changes were made to see if the target element was removed.

```
function onRemove(element, callback) {
  const parent = element.parentNode;
  if (!parent) throw new Error("The node must already be attached");

  const obs = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for (const mutation of mutations) {
      for (const el of mutation.removedNodes) {
        if (el === element) {
          obs.disconnect();
          callback();
        }
      }
    }
  });
  obs.observe(parent, {
    childList: true,
  });
}
```

then with your example instead of

```
element.onRemove(() => releaseKraken(element));
```

you can do

```
onRemove(element, () => releaseKraken(element));
```

This approach should be plenty fast if all you are doing is watching a single element. While it may seem like a decent amount of looping, it is pretty rare for `removedNodes` to be more than one node, and unless something is removing tons of siblings all at once, `mutations` is going to be quite small too.

You could also consider doing

```
callback(el);
```

which would allow you to do

```
onRemove(element, releaseKraken);
```

Comment: Thank you, @loganfsmyth. This is exactly what I'm using so far, looks like it's the lesser of evils.

Comment: please consider this edit to your answer (with my SO score, I can't propose it without applying immediately): https://gist.github.com/lolmaus/98d8c95fbd1e0a2fa59aa77a574163b9/revisions

Comment: Hey, @loganfsmyth! We ran into an issue with this solution. The problem is that when a node is removed, only that node and none of its children appear in `removedNodes`. Since any of given element's parents can be removed, instead of `if (el === element)` we need somethings like `$(givenElement).parents().toArray().includes(removedNode)`. Also, we must watch `document` and not immediate parent, and include `subtree: true` into `observe()` options.

Comment: Yup, true. You never really specified how it was getting removed, so I assumed it would be a normal removal of that specific element.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative, shorter version of loganfsmyth's excellent solution:

```js
function onRemove(el, callback) {
  new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
    if(!document.body.contains(el)) {
      observer.disconnect();
      callback();
    }
  }).observe(document.body, { childList: true });
}
```

Usage is the same:

```
onRemove(myElement, function() {
  console.log("The element was removed!");
})
```

Comment: What if the _parent_ of `el.parentNode` gets removed? Will the callback still fire?

Comment: @DavidGiven Good point! Fixed. Not sure about perf implications though. Feel free to make changes of course.

Comment: the problem with watching on body is - it will be fired for each changes thus creating performance implication.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found on [this](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/how-to-detect-if-element-is-added-or-removed-from-dom/) page

```js
document.getElementById("delete_one_div").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var divToDelete = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  divToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(divToDelete);
});

var element = document.getElementById("div_to_be_watched")
var in_dom = document.body.contains(element);
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if (in_dom && !document.body.contains(element)) {
    console.log("I was just removed");
    in_dom = false;
    observer.disconnect();
  }

});
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true });
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
<div id="div_to_be_watched">Div to be watched</div>
<div class="div_to_be_watched">Second test</div>
<button id="delete_one_div">Delete one div</button>
```

**EDIT**

I edited snippet a little bit. You have two options:

1. Use it the way it is. And it is not very memory consuming since the `if` condition is not really complicated (only to check whether the body contains an element) and it observes only to the moment of remove and then it stops,
2. Make observer observe only specific element to limit the event triggers.

Comment: Your callback will be triggered thousands or millions of times, and it will do so even after the element is removed. That's crazy overhead for a simple, narrow task.

Answer (score 0):

To observe if a specific element was removed from DOM you can use the following function.
(Remove the export keyword if you don't want to use it as an ES6 module.)
Cheers!

```
// Usage example:
// observeRemoval(document.children[0], doSomething, 'document.children[0] removed') => doSomething('document.children[0] removed') will be executed if document.children[0] is removed
// observeRemoval(document.children[0], doSomething) => doSomething(document.children[0]) will be executed if document.children[0] is removed (removed element is passed to callback function)
// observeRemoval([document.children[0], document.children[1]], doSomething) => doSomething(document.children[0]) will be executed if document.children[0] is removed (removed element is passed to callback function), doSomething(document.children[1]) will be executed if document.children[1] is removed
// observeRemoval([document.children[0], document.children[1]], doSomething, ['document.children[0] removed', 'document.children[1] removed']) => doSomething('document.children[0] removed') will be executed if document.children[0] is removed, doSomething('document.children[1] removed') will be executed if document.children[1] is removed
// observeRemoval(document.querySelectorAll('body *'), doSomething) => doSomething(<removed-element>) will be executed if any element inside the document.body is removed

export function observeRemoval(elements, callback, callbackInputs){
  let ecr = ecrTransform(elements, callback, callbackInputs);
  for(let i=0;i<ecr.elements.length;i++){
    let match = removalObserved.find(obj => obj.element === ecr.elements[i] && obj.callback === ecr.callback && obj.callbackInput === ecr.callbackInputs[i]);
    if(!match){
      removalObserved.push({
        element: ecr.elements[i],
        callback: ecr.callback,
        callbackInput: ecr.callbackInputs[i],
      });
    }
  }
}

export function unobserveRemoval(elements, callback, callbackInputs){
  let ecr = ecrTransform(elements, callback, callbackInputs);
  for(let i=0;i<removalObserved.length;i++){
    let index = removalObserved.findIndex(obj => obj.element === ecr.elements[i] && obj.callback === ecr.callback && obj.callbackInput === ecr.callbackInputs[i]);
    if(index > -1){
      removalObserved.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}

export function getRemovalObservers(elements, callback, callbackInputs){
  return removalObserved;
}

export function disconnectRemovalObserver(){
  removalObserver.disconnect();
}

export function connectRemovalObserver(){
  removalObserver.observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
}

function ecrTransform(elements, callback, callbackInputs){
  elements = transformNodeListHTMLCollectionToArray(elements);
  callbackInputs = transformNodeListHTMLCollectionToArray(callbackInputs);
  if(!Array.isArray(elements)){
    elements = [elements];
  }
  if(!Array.isArray(callbackInputs)){
    callbackInputs = [callbackInputs];
    if(callbackInputs[0] === undefined){
      callbackInputs[0] = elements[0];
    }
  }
  if(elements.length > callbackInputs.length){
    // let continuouscallbackInput = callbackInputs[callbackInputs.length-1];
    // for(let i=0;i<(elements.length - callbackInputs.length);i++){
    //   callbackInputs.push(continuouscallbackInput);
    // }
    let continuouscallbackInput = callbackInputs[callbackInputs.length-1];
    for(let i=(elements.length - callbackInputs.length);i<elements.length;i++){
      callbackInputs.push(elements[i]);
    }
  }
  return {elements, callback, callbackInputs};
}
function transformNodeListHTMLCollectionToArray(list){
  if(NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(list) || HTMLCollection.prototype.isPrototypeOf(list)){
    return Array.from(list);
  }
  return list;
}

const removalObserved = [];
const removalObserver = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  for(let m=0;m<mutations.length;m++){
    for(let i=0;i<mutations[m].removedNodes.length;i++){
      let dO = removalObserved;
        for(let j=0;j<dO.length;j++){
        if(mutations[m].removedNodes[i].contains(dO[j].element) && !document.contains(dO[j].element)){
          (dO[j].callbackInput !== undefined) ? dO[j].callback(dO[j].callbackInput) : dO[j].callback(dO[j].element);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
connectRemovalObserver();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this still requires observing parents and iterating through all their children, which is not perfectly performant.